# Gaining more confidence regarding my obligations and dealing better with the pressure

Tags: productivity

I'm a 23 years old web developer in a somewhat successful company. I have 4 years of experience on development. Since my internship, I've been through some hard times: had to do work that I didn't have the knowledge to do it, my schedules were tight, my deadlines were inhuman, and the list goes on.

Even now, as a hired developer, the list continues. I know that I've changed throughout these years. But sometimes, I still don't know how to deal with the pressure. When I had to do something that needed to be ready as soon as possible, the pressure took the best of me. I get stressed, nervous, even the "I won't make it on time...will they fire me?" - thought comes to mind sometimes.

Now I've been assigned to a new department, and it's a new reality compared to my previous one: entire programs to be delivered to the next day, people trying to save their own asses (sorry), pressure above average...

I'll confess... I'm kinda scared. And I've been growing unsatisfied with the company itself. I've been thinking of quitting here and go to another company. And after yesterday, the thought grew stronger. My productivity has not been the same, as well.

How can I deal better with this pressure? How can I improve my confidence towards my obligations? I don't want to be in a comfort-zone, but I think I was in one and I realized way too late.

Comment: Honestly? There are jobs out there with a *much* more relaxed atmosphere where you can learn and be in a *positive* environment. Life is short and you spend a long time working - so make it somewhere you will *truly* enjoy - both work and pressure-wise, and also colleague-wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pressure (stress) is both helpful and will literally suck years out of your life. Some companies intentionally create high pressure short tight deadline situations believing it helps it's employees produce more efficiently (I disagree, but that is unrelated)

Now dealing with stress from work...

- Work obligations... You say you've worked this a while keep tabs on how long things take you. If you are assigned a task with clearly less time than it should take. SAY SOMETHING! Sometimes this is simply the person under estimating the time required to accomplish a task, other times it's your employer being a slave driving a-hole. If it's the first you can get the deadline adjusted to be more reasonable, if it's the ladder... well if it happens often find someplace else to work.
- We all have our off days we slack, get distracted, ect. Whatever the problem, if you messed up you messed up, own up to it. If you need more time or help ask for it. I will keep a person around who owns up to their mistakes and asks for help over a better dev who rides a disaster right into the wall without letting anyone know. (Except if the person chronically has issues of making mistakes)
- Confidence... This is going to sound completely wrong but the best way to build confidence? Lie to yourself. At first you won't believe it at all, but overtime you'll believe in yourself a little more each day. Over time you'll gain experience to reinforce your "lies" and make them more convincing, until one day you realize your "lies" aren't lies anymore.
- And far as stay or quitting... If you're being used and abused move on. Don't let anyone ever hold you back and use you. If you're thinking of quitting because it's hard / you feel incapable of meeting expectations look yourself in the mirror, tell yourself you got this and you're a @#%#$ rockstar and get back in there!

I've been right in your shoes man, I guess what turned me around was a friend who honestly was a really nice person, but at the time he was clumsy, never pursued an education or skill, so really didn't have much to work with, but that guy would tell you he could put a man on the moon and truly believe it. (he turned out well enough) but made me realize second guessing the skills I do have was a waste, and convincing myself I'm capable of more than I necessarily am really helped me advance my career and myself. (Not that it was without mistakes... May having to hire someone to install my patio post a very long failed attempt ever act as evidence of that)

Now rockstar, get back in there!

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the "lie to yourself" part?

Comment: Well essentially the idea is since our squishy little minds are easily manipulated and malleable we're using a psychology trick to artificially reinforce our confidence.

Through repetition you can convince yourself of any lie to the point you yourself believe it's true.

So let's say you've done a few lessons in a new language. You really don't know it well yet. You sit at your computer and tell yourself you DO know what you're doing and you can nail whatever it is you're working on.

At first you KNOW you're lying, but as time goes on you'll believe it more, until experience makes it true.

Comment: Oh...i see. Thanks man. I'm more calm than yesterday. I'll think things through and will take your words in consideration.